# Sharepoint 2010 Claims in BDC

Tags: sharepoint-2010, bdc, claims

I would like my BDC ReadList()-operation to fetch objects based on email from a user claim. I tried using IClaimsPrincipal in a webpart, with no problem, but I can't get it to work in BDC model.

Basically I would like to do something like this:

ReadList()
{
1. Get Claims object
2. Get email from claims object
3. Ask query with that email
4. return query result
}

Any thoughts/ideas on this matter would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Basically I found this:

        private static IClaimsIdentity GetClaimsIdentity()
        {
            IClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as IClaimsPrincipal;
            if (claimsPrincipal != null)
            {
                return (IClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity;
            }
            return new ClaimsIdentity();
        }

Now I have the claimsIdentity. From this I can use Linq to extract the claims:

IEnumerable<Claim> claims = (from c in identity.Claims select c).Distinct().ToList<Claim>();
return claims;

Hopes this can be of help.